# How to parse mapquest geocode JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, json, parsing, nsdictionary, mapquest

I am trying to parse the JSON result from Mapquest geocode API.

```
NSDictionary *JSONReponseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:mapquestdata options:0 error:&error];
NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [JSONReponseDic objectForKey:@"results"];

NSDictionary *locationDic = [resultsArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"loc dic %@", locationDic);

NSString *city = [locationDic objectForKey:@"adminArea5"];
NSLog(@"city : %@", city);
```

I can parse until locationDic, which returns

```
loc dic {
locations =     (
            {
        adminArea1 = US;
        adminArea1Type = Country;
        adminArea3 = CA;
        adminArea3Type = State;
        adminArea4 = "Santa Clara County";
        adminArea4Type = County;
        adminArea5 = "Los Altos";
        adminArea5Type = City;
        displayLatLng =             {
            lat = "37.37964";
            lng = "-122.11877";
        };
        dragPoint = 0;
        geocodeQuality = POINT;
        geocodeQualityCode = P1AAA;
        latLng =             {
            lat = "37.37949";
            lng = "-122.11903";
        };
        linkId = 0;
        mapUrl = "http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=Fmjtd|luub206tl1,rg=o5-9ubah0&type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-1,37.37949,-122.11903,0,0|&center=37.37949,-122.11903&zoom=15&rand=-159915059";
        postalCode = "94022-2707";
        sideOfStreet = R;
        street = "145 1st St";
        type = s;
    }
);
providedLocation =     {
    location = "145 1st St,Los Altos, CA 94022";
};
}
```

Then, when I am trying to get the city name, the log returns null. Am I parsing this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `[locationDic valueForKeyPath:@"locations.adminArea5"];`.

Comment: i did `NSString *city = [locationDic objectForKey:@"locations.adminArea5"];` and it still returns `NULL`

Comment: See my edited answer. I was writing that from memory, the right method is `valueForKeyPath:` instead of `objectForKey:`.

Comment: Thanks. valuekeyforpath seems to do the job.

Comment: No problem, check your other question with Yelp API, I've just answered to that.

Comment: Actually, i can use valueforkeypath to get the city string,  but how do I get `latLng =             {
            lat = "37.37949";
            lng = "-122.11903";
        };`? sorry for the noobish question, but `NSDictionary * displayLatLngArray = [locationDic valueForKeyPath:@"latLng"];`
returns null

Comment: It has to be again like this `[locationDic valueForKeyPath:@"locations.latLng"];` :) And you probably shouldn't name a NSDictionary `displayLatLngArray` - it is a dictionary not an array.

Comment: :facepalm: sorry. getting ahead of myself here.